# JPA ManyToMany with own Table

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many

I have the following entities:

- Project: id:int, name:String, workers:Set
- Worker: id:int, name:String, projects:Set
- Project_Worker: id:int,
  project_id:int, worker_id:int

So, I have my own table to 'solve' the many to many relation. <-- ya I need it - can't use just many to many and let JPA create the table cause I need the extra entity.

Now I tried a lot. Just so that JPA wont create an own table and extra columns and so on, but it wont work. My code so far:

```
@Entity
@Table("Worker")
public class Worker implements Serializable {
...
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Project_Worker", 
       joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Worker_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
       inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
private Set<Project> projects;
```

The Project entity looks the same. just with the changed join columns.

My table: Project_Worker columns have at the moment no annotations cause if I use for example:

```
@JoinTable(name="Project",
  joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id")})
```

JPA creates in the worker and project table an extra column instead in the Project_Worker table..

So I just want to map the many-to-many relation over my own table with my own attributes.

I also tried the solution - which worked - that just the `project_worker` table will have `OneToMany` annotations, but so the project and worker entity  won't be able to use the Set and i have to look every time in the project_worker table for the right row...

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. So, you have a table `Project_Worker` which you want to use as join table, and you have/want an entity also on that table? One thing is for sure, you only need `@JoinTable` on one side of the relationship, so you can remove it from `Worker` or `Project` entity.

Comment: i have 3 classes/entities (worker, project and project_worker) im writing a little Database Programm. Thats the reason why i need that project_worker table and cant just generate one on the database cause i need the table also in my programm. I changed the code as you said - but i still get in the project_worker table additional columns

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map it as a many-to-many Project<->Worker via your join table you will need to ditch the id column in the project_worker table and it should work as you expect.

If you can't do this then you will need ProjectWorker as an entity in code then the relationship should be a one-to-many from Worker and Project to ProjectWorker.

```
@Entity
@Table("Worker")
public class Worker implements Serializable {
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "worker")
private Set<ProjectWorker> projectWorker;


@Entity
@Table("Project")
public class Project implements Serializable {
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
private Set<ProjectWorker> projectWorker;


@Entity
@Table("ProjectWorker")
public class ProjectWorker implements Serializable {
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "worker_id")
private Worker worker;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
private Project project;
```

Comment: thanks @alan - thats a great idea. but is there no solution for my problem? i mean i just want the normal many to many mapping from jpa on my own table entity. I think that will work for sure - but i search for a solution that the Worker knows his Projects (in a list) and the Projects his Workers.

Comment: You original question states you have three Entities. It would seem  that you have two. see update.

Comment: thanks for your post again. so ya i definitely need the ProjectWorker entity. So is there no other solution which will just use my projectworker table as the mapping table? even if i use your solution i will get a kinda hard editing and deleting